# LuaXML error: "undefined symbol: luaL_prepbuffer"

Tags: module, lua, luaxml

I'm using the lua interpreter and I'm trying to load [LuaXML](http://viremo.eludi.net/LuaXML/) but when I *require('LuaXML')*, I get this error.

```
lua: error loading module 'LuaXML' from file './LuaXML_lib.so':
    ./LuaXML_lib.so: undefined symbol: luaL_prepbuffer
```

I have no clue how to fix this. I tried compiling the module myself but it still throws the error.

Comment: There are no `luaL_prepbuffer` in the liblua 5.2.0.

Comment: @DreamEater: [There is one according to the documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_prepbuffer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are trying to use LuaXML under Lua 5.2.
LuaXML was designed for Lua 5.1.
The problem can be solved by installing Lua 5.1.x or LuaJIT.

Comment: Compiling LuaXML with `-DLUA_COMPAT_ALL` should allow it to be used with Lua 5.2.